# destructing es6 in array push

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i want to use something like `destructing assignment` in `ES6` for having cleaner code but i dont know how to use it in something like pushing in array or anyway can is use it or something similar?. this sample code is in `vue js`:

```
result.map((item) => {
   this.virtualWallets.push({
      credit: item.credit,
      type: item.type,
      name: item.name,
      symbol: item.symbol,
      image: item.image,
      address: item.address,
      address_tag: item.address_tag,
      auto_transfer: item.auto_transfer,
   });
});
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: this.virtualWallets.push({ ...item })

Comment: Destructuring won't really make this code much simpler. You'd have to do `result.map(({credit_formatted, type, name /*...*/}) => this.virtualWallets.push({ credit: credit_formatted, type, name /*... */}))`, so it's *mostly* moving some of the complexity elsewhere.

Comment: You can change `result.map((item) => {` by `result.map(({ credit_formatted, type, name, symbol, image, address, address_tag, auto_transfer }) => {` and delete all `item.` in the assignement.

Comment: Also, please don't use `.map` for simple iteration. Use `forEach` or a normal loop if you aren't doing a mapping operation.

Comment: the use here of an `array.map` seems to me incorrect, it would be better to use an `array.forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
result.map((item) => {
  const {credit_formatted, type, name, symbol, image, address, address_tag, auto_transfer} = item;
  this.virtualWallets.push({
    credit: credit_formatted,
    type: type,
    name: name,
    symbol: symbol,
    image: image,
    address: address,
    address_tag: address_tag,
    auto_transfer: auto_transfer,
  });
});
```

or this:

```
result.map(({credit_formatted, type, name, symbol, image, address, address_tag, auto_transfer}) => {
  this.virtualWallets.push({
    credit: credit_formatted,
    type: type,
    name: name,
    symbol: symbol,
    image: image,
    address: address,
    address_tag: address_tag,
    auto_transfer: auto_transfer,
  });
});
```

And then you can remove unnecessary words, like this:

```
result.map(({credit_formatted, type, name, symbol, image, address, address_tag, auto_transfer}) => {
  this.virtualWallets.push({
    credit: credit_formatted,
    type,
    name,
    symbol,
    image,
    address,
    address_tag,
    auto_transfer,
  });
});
```

Comment: And those variants are easier/"cleaner" than OPs script because...?

Comment: could you tell me solution for somthing like this? `let virtualWallet = this.virtualWallets.find(wallet => wallet.symbol === 'x'); this.selectedVirtualWallet.name = virtualWallet.name; this.selectedVirtualWallet.symbol = virtualWallet.symbol; this.selectedVirtualWallet.credit = virtualWallet.credit; this.selectedVirtualWallet.address_tag = virtualWallet.address_tag;`

Comment: Then you should make a const like this:

`let virtualWallet = this.virtualWallets.find(wallet => wallet.symbol === 'x');`
then 
` const {name, symbol, credit, address_tag} = virtualWallet`
and 
`this.selectedVirtualWallet.name = name;`
`this.selectedVirtualWallet.symbol = symbol`
...

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this.

```
result.map(({credit_formatted, type, name, symbol, image, address, address_tag, auto_transfer}) => {
      this.virtualWallets.push({
        credit: credit_formatted,
        type,
        name,
        symbol,
        image,
        address,
        address_tag,
        auto_transfer,
      });
    });
```

Comment: could you tell me solution for this ?

Comment: let virtualWallet = this.virtualWallets.find(wallet => wallet.symbol === 'x');
                this.selectedVirtualWallet.name = virtualWallet.name;
                this.selectedVirtualWallet.symbol = virtualWallet.symbol;
                this.selectedVirtualWallet.credit = virtualWallet.credit;
                this.selectedVirtualWallet.address_tag = virtualWallet.address_tag;

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to @Athish Murugan's answer:

You can also destructure like this:

```
let virtualWallet = this.virtualWallets.find(wallet => wallet.symbol === 'x');

const [name, symbol, credit, address_tag] = virtualWallet;

this.selectedVirtualWallet.name = name;
this.selectedVirtualWallet.symbol = symbol;
this.selectedVirtualWallet.credit = credit;
this.selectedVirtualWallet.address_tag = address_tag;;
```